# What is the fastest and/or most idiomatic way of finding out whether an object column has multiple datatypes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column like this:

```
df.Chromosome
# 0        1
# 1        1
# 2        1
# 3        1
# 4        1
#         ..
# 94391    Y
# 94392    Y
# 94393    Y
# 94394    Y
# 94395    Y
# Name: Chromosome, Length: 94396, dtype: object
```

By doing `df.Chromosome.apply(type).drop_duplicates()` I find that it consists of two types of data:

```
0        <class 'int'>
65536    <class 'str'>
Name: Chromosome, dtype: object
```

Is there a faster and more idiomatic way of checking whether a column consists of multiple dtypes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your solution is nice, another alternatives:

```
df.Chromosome.map(type).unique()
```

---

```
set(df.Chromosome.map(type))
```

Also is possible first remove duplicates in values for improve performance:

```
df.Chromosome.drop_duplicates().apply(type).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

`df.applymap(type).drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative -

```
{type(_) for _ in set(df.Chromosome.value_counts().index)}
```

This is quite slow